# What is the clearest font on iphone device (3G/3GS/4)?

Tags: iphone, fonts

what is the font that is rendered perfectly on iphone, in particular 3G that is old...

I need to write text, but my Georgia don't satisfy me.

Some of text are very small, about 8/9 points. Is there a font type that don't pixelate on device?

Any suggestion?

thanks,
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, two of Apple's most used and prefered fonst...
**Helvetiva and Myriad Pro**

Answer (score 0):

Just use the system font. I can still read it at 6 point on my iPhone 4.

If you're really serious about this, you can render the fonts yourself using OpenGL.

Comment: ...how can i render my font with opengl?

Comment: And just out of interest. What's the default system font?